# unexplained undefined string displayed on my website. not sure how to get rid of it

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have a undefined string being displayed on my page and i have no idea why it is their besides the function that is probably causing it, i only know this from displaying allot of console errors to locate the problem. 
I believe that Mustache is doing this somehow when i call on templates.
[image]
    
    "
    undefined
        "

The question is  how do i get rid of this undefined string being injected in my page. Any help would be much appreciated.

Code:Function that is being called that is somehow or reason displaying a undefined string in my div

```
 getProjects: function(){
            portfolio.topOfPage();
            var request1 = $.ajax({
                url: "js/projects.js",
                dataType:'json',
                cache: true,
            }).then(function(response){
                var data = response.projects;
                var template = $('#projects_tmp').html();
                var projects;
                $.each(data, function(key,val){
                    console.log("Key: "+key+", Value: "+val);
                     projects += Mustache.to_html(template, val);
                });
                return projects;
            });
```

My mustache template:

```
<script id="projects_tmp" type="text/template">
        <div class='small-6 medium-3 large-2 columns left thumb {{{genre}}}' data-id='{{{id}}}'>
            <div class='project'><figure><img src='{{{largePic}}}' alt='' />
            <figcaption class='caption'><span>{{genre}}</span></figcaption class='caption'></figure></div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: I added everything i though you might need to help

Comment: I am two days new with Mustache and templating so if it is a stupid solution keep that in mind haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is your `projects` variable should have a default value of '', in your getProjects method when you are doing `projects +=` it is adding undefined value which comes by default.

Comment: You wouldnt happen to know how to do the same code i did with templating but by using {{#projects}}{{/projects}}? i am confused on how to use these tags and my code usualy ends up breaking.

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 `</div>` and just 2 `<div>` in your code posted above. Not sure if that might be the issue.